# Low wifi signal on Windows 10 and HP laptop without no apparent reason

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, laptop

I'm using an HP laptop with both Windows 10 (upgraded from windows 8) and Ubuntu 14.06.

Ubuntu is loading from an external hard drive (so not dual boot installation was required).

Now I'm getting a very low wifi signal on my laptop when using Windows, even though I'm very close to the router and other laptops/cellphones in the same area pick up a very strong signal. Occasionally my laptop also disconnects itself, maybe because the signal is too low (on some diagnositc I find it to be as low as -90dB) which, again, is very weird since the other machines seem to work fine.

When using Ubuntu 14.06 the wifi connection works fine (I get almost full signal) so I would rule out any problem to the hardware and focus on Windows 10.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What brand is your wireless NIC on the laptop and what frequencies are you connecting to on Windows and on Ubuntu? 2.4GHz or 5GHz?

Comment: The brand is Realtek RTL8723BE 802.11 bgn. How can I check the frequency? I think it should be the default value since I haven't changed anything...

Comment: Depends on the setup of your wireless router, normally both frequencies would be announced via two different SSIDs. If you know how to, you should check your wireless router to see what the configuration is.

Comment: Found it! 2.4 GHz

Comment: Try this: Open settings > search 'network adapter' > choose device manager > choose network adapters > choose Realtek RTL8723BE Wireless LAN NIC > click on the advanced tab > click on wireless mode > change 'Auto' to IEEE 802.11 g/b, see if that helps.

Comment: At the time of writing I have the following options available: 802.11b, 802.11g and 802.11b/g. 802.11b/g is the option currently selected.

Comment: Right, then i'm not sure what it could be, but i hope someone else might have an idea. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue myself by simply downgrading the wifi network adapter driver.

The procedure I followed was:

1. Open device manager
2. Right click on the network adapter and select "Update driver"
3. Click on "Look for the driver in the computer"
4. Click "Choose from available driver"
5. Then select the one you wish to install/downgrade to.

It worked, now I get mid-full signal. I think the problem should be some kind of compatibility between the new driver and Windows 10. My two cents anyway...